# CMake: parallel builds with explicit target and their inter-dependencies?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm using `cmake` which generates GNU Makefiles which I execute with `make` in a GCC-based environment. After some years of using it only now realized that I have problem:

Imagine this is my CMakelists.txt:

```
add_library(lib1 STATIC empty.cpp)
add_library(lib2 STATIC empty.cpp)
add_library(lib3 STATIC empty.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main lib1 lib2 lib3)
```

(empty.cpp is empty and main.cpp is void main(void){})

I then run `cmake` and `make -j4`. It works as expected: it builds lib1, lib2 and lib3 in parallel and links it to main.

However, if I run `make -j4 main lib1` (thus stating the main and lib1 target explicitly) it builds lib1 twice. Output:

```
[200%] [300%] [300%] [300%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/empty.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib3.dir/empty.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/empty.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/empty.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library liblib1.a
Linking CXX static library liblib3.a
Linking CXX static library liblib2.a
Linking CXX static library liblib1.a
[300%] Built target lib1
[300%] Built target lib1
[  0%] Built target lib3
Built target lib2
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable main
Built target main
```

Is this normal? Why does make not realize that lib1 is invoked twice? Is this a problem in cmake or make? Is there work-around or a correct way to do it? Is this a problem at all?

Answer (score 1):

It is *normal behavior*. It does realize that `lib1` is invoked twice but it's just checking whether `lib1` is built or not.

Say for `main` it built `lib1`. But for `lib1` target which you specified *explicitly*, it again checks for the same.